# I don't understand why I need to put two lines in a specific order for it to work (recursion)

Tags: c++

I just started to learn about recursion.

This program is supposed to calculate n! and store the result into an output parameter.

```
void factorial(int n, int &f)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        f = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        factorial(n - 1, f);
        f *= n;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int f;
    factorial(5, f);
    cout << f;
}
```

This way it works perfectly. In my first attempt, the else condition looked like this

```
else
    {
    f *= n;
        factorial(n - 1, f);
    }
```

and the program didn't output anything but 1.

I really can't understand why it works in the first way but in the second it doesn't. Can you explain to me?

Comment: The only way for you to understand this is to write out the execution of this function on a piece of paper. How, for example, is `factorial(3, f)` executed, step by step? How does switching the order of these statements affect the process?

Comment: You are right. I did and I got it haha. Thanks.

Comment: Because your function `factorial` is written in a counter-intuitive, hard-to-reason-about way. Make it `int factorial(int n)` like every little obedient citizen and your problem disappears. The only reasonable way to use is to `return n*factorial(n-1);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `factorial(0, f)` will set `f = 1`. If you modify `f` before the call to `factorial`, it will be overwritten.

Note that this problem is not possible if you return `int` instead of taking `int &` as an argument.

Comment: Yeah. I ran it on paper and I got it. Thanks a lot tho, I will accept your answer asap.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering:
Using @ForceBru's suggestion I ran it on a piece of paper and I got it. If I do it in the second way, the last thing called will be factorial(0) which will return 1, even if I already calculated to be n!.

Answer (score 0):

f is getting over written to 1 in your last call f(0). If you switch the statements then f gets initialized to 1 in the last call f(0) followed by It's modification before return of each function call